# dart angular2 - non standard javascript event

Tags: angular, dart

I'd like to listen on a non standard javascript event `dp.change`.

How can I do this ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to any event this way

```
someElement.on['dp.change'].listen(...)
```

or

```
window.on['dp.change'].listen(...)
```